# Django query objects grouped on field

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

If I have a django model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    given_names = models.CharField(max_length=144)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=144)
```

I want to construct a query that will return all the people in the database, grouped by their surnames.  It should return something like this:

```
{
    'Smith': [<Person: Joseph A Smith>, <Person: Joseph B Smith>],
    'Bloggs': [<Person: Joseph A Bloggs>, <Person: Joseph B Bloggs>],
    ...
}
```

What's the best way to construct this query?

Comment: Is `[<Person: Joseph A Smith>, <Person: Joseph B Smith>]` list or queryset?

Comment: For my current case, it doesn't matter.  Let's say queryset, for the sake of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
persons = Person.objects.all()
for person in persons:
    result[person.surname].append(person)
```

Problem is surnames like "SMith", "SMITH" or " Smith". In this case replacing `result[person.surname]...` with `result[person.surname.strip().lower()]...` can help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do exactly what you're asking for is to create a queryset for each individual surname, loop through the surnames, and add them to a dict like so:

```
for name in Person.objects.values('surname').distinct():
    qs = Person.objects.filter(surname__icontains=name)
    your_dict[name] = qs
```

And add that to a dictionary.

You might also consider making surnames their own model with a foreignkey to `Person`. You can just loop through all the surnames like:

```
for s in Surname.objects.all():
    people = Person.objects.filter(surname=s.name)
    your_dict[s.name] = people
```

Last, you could drop to raw SQL, trying something like the following if you're using MySQL (you'd need something different for Postgres):

```
people = Person.objects.raw(
    'SELECT surname, GROUP_CONCAT(given_names) FROM personapp_person GROUP BY surname'
)
```

but I think the other solutions would be easier in the end.

Comment: Hmmm.  I was hoping for an answer that could do it all in one query.  By the way, you can get all the distinct surnames directly with `Person.objects.values('surname').distinct()` - no need for the first loop.

Comment: @Tom thanks, great feedback! I don't think this is possible using the ORM directly, but you could try raw SQL depending on your database type...updated my answer.